# A way to display image in PHP without <img src=>

Tags: php, html, image, apache

Is there a way to display any kind of image preferably in PHP without the `<img src=""/>` tag?

I tried `imagepng` but is there one to work for all kinds of image files?.

I want it to be able to display the image where it is determined by a link for example:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('/imgs/user/logo.png');
imgpng('http://example.com$img');
```

So it will directly display the image from the URL together with the `$img` variable. I need it to have a `$img` variable as it will be using the `REQUEST_URI` forwarding.

I don't want to use `<img src="">` because I cannot embed the image again or it will not show.

Is there a way around this as I need to add some other code for analytics at the same time in the PHP where if I add it in the html file, the image wont render properly if re-shared again.

Comment: Depending on image type, use imagejpeg, imagegif or imagepng

Comment: Why don't you just let the webserver serve the file directly? Is there any practical need why you need PHP to serve the file?

Comment: You can't display images without and img tag. PHP doesn't render in the browser. HTML renders in the browser.

Comment: you seem to be confusing HTML `<img ..` with I'm not sure what

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: You seem to just be confused...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol oh good its not just me then :-)

Comment: that's massively wasteful of cpu resources. you force PHP to download the image, decompress it into a raw bitmap in memory, then REcompress it into a png. if you just want the file to be output, `readfile('/imgs/user/logo.php')` would be FAR more efficient.

Comment: @lansen Yes, you can, provided you use the correct header, no problem with that

Comment: Hi, it's because i need to add other code for analytics when displaying the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [readfile:](http://php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php)

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
$image = 'path/to/image.jpg';
readfile($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an image with an HTTP response instead of a normal webpage.

```
<?php
$file= '/images/image.png';
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

fpassthru($fp);
```

Obviously if the image is not a PNG, changhe the `Content-Type` to the right format, for example `image/jpg` .